# Ошибка вызова presentviewcontroller

Tags: xcode, iphone, objective-c

Господа прошу помощи, сам не могу разобраться...пока
Есть FVC и SVC. В FVC есть кнопка связанная с SVC по modal, при нажатии SVC открывается все норм.
Но в процессе работы FVC есть необходимость показать SVC без нажатия на кнопку и вернуться обратно.
Я делаю так:
в .h файле:

import "SVC.h"

в .m

```
if (условие) {
 SVC *secondViewController = [[SVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SVC" bundle:nil];
 [self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Но при выполнении и срабатывании условия, исполнение прерывается с ошибкой:
Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle ........ (loaded)' with name 'SVC''

Может я не правильно пытаюсь отобразить SVC?

Comment: Если вдруг важно -  и тот и другой контроллер описаны и нарисованы со всеми элементами в сторибоарде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если они описаны в сториборде, зачем вы делаете `[[SVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SVC" bundle:nil];`?

либо в том же сториборде опишите segue, назовите как-нибудь типа "SVC", а затем `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SVC" sender:self];` или если по каким-то причинам segue использовать не хочется, то задайте своему презентуемому UIVIewController storyboard ID = @"SVC" далее `[self presentViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SVC"] animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: Спасибо большое, понял глобальную ошибку. Все получилось.